# Reload googlemaps after user clicks a link in Django

Tags: django, google-maps

I am doing a project in Django and i want to have some google maps displayed in my site. So, i installed django-easy-maps and successfully used it in a sample template. So, i am ready with my maps.
The interface i want to implement is this

http://i49.tinypic.com/sowm74.png

I want to display the maps where the Hellow World! container is and with different links on the sidebar i want to refresh the map being displayed on user click without reloading the page.
I did some researching and it seems Ajax is the solution...
Can anybody tell me how i might achieve this (with or without Ajax ) ?
Sorry for sounding like a noob but i am fairly new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic steps are:

- Create a view for the Google Maps section to the right. This view does not return a full HTML page but only the HTML for that section (which contains your Google Maps map).
- When the user clicks on a link on the left, use JavaScript to perform an ajax call to request that page. In short this means: attach an event handler to the `onclick` event of those links and in code you can perform an ajax call .Many people use a JavaScript library for this purpose, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (which has [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).
- You can then use JavaScript to put the received HTML inside the container on the right (using [`$.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)).